# Open Cordova app at last page visited

Tags: cordova

I have a cordova app that also has various html pages that can be accessed.  But the app opens always to the homepage.

Is there a way to reopen the app from the last page visited?

Maybe something like pass the current page as var, and open this or if empty open index?

Comment: You can store the current page on a page change for example in localStorage, and use that variable to open that page when started

Comment: which files would I edit to do this?

Comment: Depends on your app's architecture. Is it an Angular app? Ionic? ..

Comment: This one just basic HTML/CSS/JS like a website.  no architecture.

Comment: "The app always opens to the homepage" This statement says that you have some page method implemented. When you change the page, store the value to localStorage

Comment: its a cordova app as the question.  Im guessing its from the config <content src="index.html" />

Comment: I really can't tell without knowing how your app's navigation is set up. Please share some relevant code

Comment: a website.  <a href="page2.html>

Answer (score 2):

You can catch several events in cordova, for example the pause event. Here is an example in vanillascript:

```
var _storageKey = "lastPage";

// cordova ready, load last page
document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceReady, false);

function deviceReady () {

    var lastPage = localStorage.getItem(_storageKey);
    if (lastPage && window.location.pathname != lastPage) {
        window.location.pathname = lastPage;
    }

    // store location when app is paused/closed
    document.addEventListener("pause", saveCurrentPage, false);
}

// store navigation
function saveCurrentPage () {
    localStorage.setItem(_storageKey, window.location.pathname);
});
```

Comment: where is this code supposed to go?  I tried it in index, but doesnt open on lastPage